# Regular expression Variant

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to extract the length of a dress from a pandas dataframe .The row of that dataframe looks like this :

`A-line dress with darting at front and back | Surplice neckline | Long sleeves | About 23" from shoulder to hem | Triacetate/polyester | Dry clean | Imported | Model shown is 5'10" (177cm) wearing a size 4`

As you can see the size is contained between About and shoulder but in some cases shoulder is replaced by waist,hem etc.Below is my python script that finds the length but it fails when lets say there is a comma after `About` since i am slicing the list.

```
import re

def regexfinder(string_var):

    res=''

    x=re.search(r"(?<=About).*?(?=[shoulder,waist,hem,bust,neck,bust,top,hips])", string_var).group(0)
    tohave=int(x[1:3])

    if tohave >=16 and tohave<=36:
        res="Mini"
        return res

    if tohave>36 and tohave<40:
        res="Above the Knee"
        return res

    if tohave >=40 and tohave<=46:
        res="Knee length"
        return res

    if tohave>46 and tohave<49:
        res="Mid/Tea length"
        return res

    if tohave >=49 and tohave<=59:
        res="Long/Maxi length"
        return res

    if tohave>59:
        res="Floor Length"
        return res
```

Comment: Example where my code fails : ```'Velvet dress featuring mesh front, back and sleeves | Crewneck | Long bell sleeves | Self-tie closure at back cutout | About, 31" from shoulder to hem | Viscose/nylon | Hand wash | Imported | Model shown is 5\'10" (177cm) wearing a size Small.'1```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = """A-line dress with darting at front and back | Surplice neckline | Long sleeves | About 23" from shoulder to hem | Triacetate/polyester | Dry clean | Imported | Model shown is 5'10" (177cm) wearing a size 4"""
q = """'Velvet dress featuring mesh front, back and sleeves | Crewneck | Long bell sleeves | Self-tie closure at back cutout | About, 31" from shoulder to hem | Viscose/nylon | Hand wash | Imported | Model shown is 5\'10" (177cm) wearing a size Small.'1"""


def getSize(stringVal, strtoCheck): 
    for i in stringVal.split("|"):    #Split string by "|"
        if i.strip().startswith(strtoCheck):   #Check if string startswith "About"
            val =  i.strip()
            return re.findall("\d+", val)[0]    #Extract int

print getSize(s, "About")
print getSize(q, "About")
```

**Output**:

```
23
31
```

Comment: What if the ```About``` in the string is not what I am looking for?

Comment: You can then have that as an additional argument in the function. Updated snippet

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `(?<=About).*?(?=[shoulder,waist,hem,bust,neck,bust,top,hips])` uses a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for the words *shoulder,waist,hem,bust,neck,bust,top,hips*.

I think you want to put them in a non capturing group using an or `|`.

Try it like this using an optional comma `,?`:

[`(?<=About),? (\d+)(?=.*?(?:shoulder|waist|hem|bust|neck|bust|top|hips]))`](https://regex101.com/r/DXg4fR/1)

The size is in the first capturing group.

Comment: Thanks for the help!